# NG-Show Irritating Image Displacement

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, boolean, ng-show

This is an issue that's been plaguing my app since I wrote this section weeks ago. Basically I've got two images that should be displayed one at a time based on a boolean value. Using the `ng-show` directive, when I update the variable twice, the heart image is displaced, as if the other is still in place and invisible (which I'm sure is likely the case).

```
<i class="icon icon-accessory">
  <img class="padding-basic-right" src="img/love.svg" width="48px" ng-show="track.loved"/>
  <img class="padding-basic-right" src="img/skip.svg" width="48px" ng-show="!track.loved"/>
</i>
```

[image]

Is there a fix for this/a better solution? I can live with it for now, but for polish's sake it needs fixing.

Comment: Worked beautifully, thank you ever so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-src` with conditional `{{}}` interpolation directive.

```
ng-src="{{ track.loved ? 'img/love.svg': 'img/skip.svg'}}"
```

Other alternative would be using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`

```
<i class="icon icon-accessory">
  <img class="padding-basic-right" src="img/love.svg" width="48px" ng-if="track.loved"/>
  <img class="padding-basic-right" src="img/skip.svg" width="48px" ng-if="!track.loved"/>
</i>
```

Comment: This also works great, thanks a bunch for your answer!

Comment: @TomSykes oh. glad to hear that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause of your issue is that your CSS is overriding the .ng-hide CSS class Angular adds to your image when ngShow resolves to true.  Try using the ng-if directive instead -- this will cause the img tag that isn't in use to be removed from the DOM entirely.